# How do you achieve text scrolling inside a canvas

Tags: scroll, three.js, html5-canvas

I have the code below which renders a text on canvas, that refracts to the 3D object, I want to make the text scroll with the mouse wheel either using translate but cannot seem to make it bind, is there a way to achieve that?

I have done word wrap with lineheight and make the font text not blurry on HD Monitors on the different functions but cannot seem to achieve the scrolling only, any help would be much appreciated thank you.

```
function printAtWordWrap(context, text, x, y, lineHeight, fitWidth) {
      fitWidth = fitWidth || 0;

      if (fitWidth <= 0) {
        context.fillText(text, x, y);
        return;
      }
      var words = text.split(' ');
      var currentLine = 0;
      var idx = 1;
      while (words.length > 0 && idx <= words.length) {
        var str = words.slice(0, idx).join(' ');
        var w = context.measureText(str).width;
        if (w > fitWidth) {
          if (idx == 1) {
            idx = 2;
          }
          context.fillText(words.slice(0, idx - 1).join(' '), x, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
          currentLine++;
          words = words.splice(idx - 1);
          idx = 1;
        } else {
          idx++;
        }
      }

      if (idx > 0)
        context.fillText(words.join(' '), x, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
    }

    var PIXEL_RATIO = (function() {
      var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

      return dpr / bsr;
    })();
    let can;

    function createHiDPICanvas(w, h, ratio) {
      if (!ratio) {
        ratio = PIXEL_RATIO;
      }
      can = document.createElement('canvas');
      can.width = w * ratio;
      can.height = h * ratio;
      can.style.width = w + "px";
      can.style.height = h + "px";
      can.getContext("2d").setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
      return can;
    }

    //Create canvas with a custom resolution.
    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
      var myCanvas = createHiDPICanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 4);
    } else {
      var myCanvas = createHiDPICanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 2);
    }

    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d', {
      alpha: false,
      antialias: false
    });

    let x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var y = window.innerHeight / 2;
    ctx.translate(0, 200);

    const font = new FontFace("MyCanvasFont", "url(https://use.typekit.net/af/2759ad/00000000000000007735a2d2/30/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n3&v=3)");
    document.fonts.add(font);
    ctx.font = '300 150px "MyCanvasFont"';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    var txt = 'CONNECTING BRANDS TO HUMANS THROUGH CULTURE, DESIGN AND TECHNOLOGY';

    printAtWordWrap(ctx, txt, x, y, 120, window.innerWidth / 2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is: You need know how the first line to show. You can use a param to control this.

```js
    function printAtWordWrap(context, text, x, y, lineHeight, fitWidth, line)
```

control what line can show:

```js
    if(currentLine >= line){
        //remove line value of currentline
        context.fillText(words.slice(0, idx - 1).join(' '), x, y + (lineHeight * (currentLine - line) )); }
```

Note that ai remove line value of currentLin to up in canvas position.

Look my project: https://codepen.io/Luis4raujo/pen/xxRrmoE

If you can up lines instead hide, you need remove if statement (line 24)

If this answer help you, vote or check as correnct!

Comment: Thank you very much Luis, yes it did help me!